# .html() not displaying fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying to use .html() to display out the resident id, name and telephone number. However, there is nothing appearing on my page. When I check my console for any errors, there were none. There is no error with the php and residentid is in the localstorage.

html

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content" id="main-ui">
    <div id="txtresidentid"></div>
    <div id="txtresident_name"></div>
    <div id="txtresident_telephone_home"></div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
(function () {
    var residentid;
    var resident_name;
    var resident_telephone_home;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        getProfile();
    });

    function getProfile() {
        var url = serverURL() + "/getresidentprofile.php";

        var JSONObject = {
            "residentid": localStorage.getItem("residentid")
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            data: JSONObject,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (arr) {
                _getProfileResult(arr);
            },
            error: function () {
                validationMsg();
            }
        });
    }

    function _getProfileResult(arr) {
        residentid = arr[0].residentid;
        resident_name = arr[0].resident_name;
        resident_telephone_home = arr[0].resident_telephone_home;

        $("#txtresidentid").html("Residentid : " + residentid);
        $("#txtresident_name").html("Name: " + resident_name);
        $("#txtresident_telephone_home").html("Telephone(Home): " + resident_telephone_home);
    }
})();
```

Comment: show us the value of `console.log(arr);`Are you sure `_getProfileResult` got called?

Comment: write console.log in error function I think You get error

Comment: There's no error in the console as you're not reporting the error / you're swallowing the error and ignoring it.   Add to your `$.ajax` call: `error: function(jqHXR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(jqHXR, textStatus, errorThrown); }`

Comment: You're clearly not getting back what you expect to get back.  There's nothing wrong with `.html()` - you can (**and should**) *easily* test this by generating `arr` in javascript and passing it to `getProfileResult()`.  Without knowing what `arr` is set to from the ajax call (as requested by the first comment), any suggestions will be pure guess work.

Comment: show us your json example

Comment: show us the value of `console.log(arr);`. put it inside `success` before `_getProfileResult(arr);` and then run the code and check browser console tab. paste the result in your question by editing it. Then only you will get a solution.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$("#txtresidentid").append("Residentid : " + residentid);
$("#txtresident_name").append("Name: " + resident_name);
$("#txtresident_telephone_home").append("Telephone(Home): " + resident_telephone_home);
```

Comment: Despite the question's title, the issue is nothing to do with `.html()`